# Musical note string (C#-4, F-3, etc.) to MIDI note value, in Python

Tags: string, format, int, midi

The code in my answer below converts musical notes in strings, such as `C#-4` or `F-3`, to their corresponding MIDI note values.

I am posting this because I am tired of trying to dig it up online every time I need it.  I'm sure I'm not the only one who can find a use for it. I just wrote this up — it is tested and correct.  It's in Python, but I feel that it pretty close to universally understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#Input is string in the form C#-4, Db-4, or F-3. If your implementation doesn't use the hyphen, 
#just replace the line :
#    letter = midstr.split('-')[0].upper()
#with:
#    letter = midstr[:-1]
def MidiStringToInt(midstr):
    Notes = [["C"],["C#","Db"],["D"],["D#","Eb"],["E"],["F"],["F#","Gb"],["G"],["G#","Ab"],["A"],["A#","Bb"],["B"]]
    answer = 0
    i = 0
    #Note
    letter = midstr.split('-')[0].upper()
    for note in Notes:
        for form in note:
            if letter.upper() == form:
                answer = i
                break;
        i += 1
    #Octave
    answer += (int(midstr[-1]))*12
    return answer
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
NOTES_FLAT = ['C', 'Db', 'D', 'Eb', 'E', 'F', 'Gb', 'G', 'Ab', 'A', 'Bb', 'B']
NOTES_SHARP = ['C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#', 'A', 'A#', 'B']

def NoteToMidi(KeyOctave):
    # KeyOctave is formatted like 'C#3'
    key = KeyOctave[:-1]  # eg C, Db
    octave = KeyOctave[-1]   # eg 3, 4
    answer = -1

    try:
        if 'b' in key:
            pos = NOTES_FLAT.index(key)
        else:
            pos = NOTES_SHARP.index(key)
    except:
        print('The key is not valid', key)
        return answer

    answer += pos + 12 * (int(octave) + 1) + 1
    return answer
```